# Laravel 5.2.11, sessions are not working, session cookie not being set

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, I have learned about the models, views, blade, controllers and routes and how they work together. So far everything has been working smoothly.

I'm having trouble with sessions though.

When I use the AuthController that comes with Laravel and hit auth/register with a POST request, the data for the user that I register does get inserted into the users table (using mysql) and I do get back a response with the "Location" header redirecting to / like it does out of the box. It redirects like it should. But in the same response there is no "Set-Cookie" header set/sent. The session part of Laravel is not working properly for me. This is the same for a POST to auth/login, it authenticates properly and redirects to the profile page but no session cookie is sent back in the response.

I'm using:

- Laravel 5.2.11
- PHP 5.5.9
- xubuntu 14.04 (Ubuntu)
- Linux kernel 3.19.0-42-generic
- Composer 1.0

All of the php modules that Laravel requires are installed. I'm running the app with php's built in web server. I run that with sudo. The exact command I run is this:

```
sudo php -S localhost:8888 -t public/
```

All routes are being responded to properly.

I have tried both ways of installing Laravel that the installation docs recommend, through the laravel executable and composer create-project. Still no cookies set either way. I have made all the files and directories of the laravel project mod 777. The app key is set in .env if that makes any difference.

The config/session.php file is using the file driver for the session.
There are no session files in the storage/framework/sessions directory after setting a session.

When I try setting a session myself with the session function like it states in the docs:

```
session(['sesskey' => 'somevalue']);
```

Again no "Set-Cookie" header is sent in the response and no session file is created. There are no error messages reported back either I should add.

When I do set a session key with the session function like above I can get that value back however and echo it back to the browser like so:

```
echo session('sesskey');
```

So it does seem to save it at least in php's memory.

When I try setting a cookie using the withCookie method, I do get the proper response with the Set-Cookie header set:

```
return response()->view('welcome')->withCookie(cookie("test", "val" , 3600));
```

I tried going down the illuminate rabbit hole to see if I could find a problem but that is a bit over my head atm.

Any help would be much appriciated, thanks!

Comment: I assume all these routes have the 'web' middleware applied?

Comment: The routes file does contain that yes.

Comment: and all the routes that aren't working correctly are in that group?

Comment: That was the problem! That was not pointed out on the laravel docs though, at least not on the session page. Thanks! I put all of the routes in that function/closure. Now I get a token mismatch exception. Will figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: hehe it happens. It is commented in the routes.php file  [routes.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/routes.php#L25) its just doesn't explicitly say it the way people would think :)

Answer (score 10):

in laravel 5.2 you need to use "web" middleware for your problem,like that

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
//
});
```

Comment: Thank you as well. Yes the routes that will be using sessions will have to be contained within the function for the web middleware. I guess a beginner should go through the laravel doc material and the tutorials on the site. I've seen this question being asked before about sessions not persisting but I did not see an answer of anyone mentioning the web middleware.

Comment: you are right @LarryLawless every beginner should go through the laravel doc material and the tutorials on the site.

Answer (score 0):

use middleware for the request \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class

```
Route::group(['middleware' => [\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class]], function () {

});
```