# Laravel 5.3 session cookies are not creating in browser

Tags: session, laravel-5.3, token

I am facing token mismatch issue in new server while working fine in localhost. I have tried every possible way to clear cache and give SESSION_DOMAIN path in env but all seems useless.

Also session cookies are not being created in web browser while creating in storage/framework/session folder.

Please help me !

Comment: Does your Laravel application have permission to write to the storage? What session driver are you using in your .env file?

Comment: yes storage has write permissions and session driver is file. I can see session created in server but no session in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting `tokenMismatchException` exception?

If yes, some of the possible reasons are:

1. Check your files for PHP end tag "?>", if exists remove it. For more detail refer to this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/laravel-54-is-not-setting-cookies-when-uploaded-to-server).
2. You may need to use `web` middleware. For more detail refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34975051/7088500) (although it is about laravel 5.2 but, it may work for your situation too).

Comment: unfortunately there was one white space after ?>, cost a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is checking for `web` middleware presence. Normally it should be automatically applied to routes/web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    <routes>
});
```

Also check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade to see if you have any code that might have been influenced by this update.

And lastly, it would be nice if you could post a piece of code which is responsible for sessions in your app.